# Making memory game with raspberry pi and can't figure out what's wrong

Tags: rpi.gpio

What I want to make is a memory game. So 10 segment LED bar shows randomly generated pattern for 5 seconds and turn it off. Then player use on and off button to input the pattern they memorized and result will be shown either greed led or red led turns on. But anytime I press on button red led turns on.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import random
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

led_pins = [21,26,19,13,6,5,22,27,17,4]
green_led_pin = 23
red_led_pin = 16
button_on_pin = 12
button_off_pin = 25

for pin in led_pins:
    GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.setup(button_on_pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(button_off_pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

GPIO.setup(green_led_pin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(red_led_pin, GPIO.OUT)

def show_pattern(pattern):
    for i, pin in enumerate(led_pins):
        GPIO.output(pin, pattern[i])
    time.sleep(5)
    for pin in led_pins:
        GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)

def get_player_input():
    player_pattern = []
    for i in range(10):
        while True:
            if GPIO.input(button_on_pin) == GPIO.LOW:
                player_pattern.append(GPIO.HIGH)
                break
            elif GPIO.input(button_off_pin) == GPIO.LOW:
                break
    return player_pattern

while True:
    pattern = [random.choice([GPIO.HIGH,GPIO.LOW]) for i in range(10)]
    show_pattern(pattern)
    input_pattern = get_player_input()
    if input_pattern == pattern:
        GPIO.output(green_led_pin, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(2)
        GPIO.output(green_led_pin, GPIO.LOW)
    else:
        GPIO.output(red_led_pin, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(2)
        GPIO.output(red_led_pin, GPIO.LOW)
```

Comment: You need de-bouncing logic in your code. this could be as simple as a sleep after you detect the state change( to 'skip' the following false button presses) or you may need more complex de-bouncing logic depending on what user experience your looking for, and how noisy those switches are.

Comment: To prove this to your self, and see whats happening, try adding a print statement above both the "break" statements in get_player_input()   you will see that a single button press will probably be counted for all 10, since there is no waiting for the line to change states again.

Comment: Let say the random is selected 5. The I will press button on to memorized the pattern for 5 led. Is that right?

Comment: This is an interesting project, and the community understands what you're trying to do. It looks like you've posted a piece of code, and described that it is doing exactly what it's supposed to. For future reference, it's conventional to ask a question.